# How many processes can be in created state in UNIX depending of the number of cores?

Tags: unix, process, operating-system

Here are UNIX process states.

[image]

My question is:

How many processes can be found **at one time** in each state depending of the number of cores?

For user running, kernel running is the **number of cores**.

For Ready to run/in memory, Ready to run/Swapped, Asleep in Memory, Sleep/Swapped, Zombie - **as many**

But I still cannot find the answer for created and preempted states. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: The premise of this question is wrong, the theoretical number of processes a certain system can have is not dependent of the number of CPU cores but the amount of available memory. That means that there is no possible way to actually say the *practical* maximum number of processes of a single system, as the amount of available memory depends on the actual processes running. The amount of processes a system can have is also *not* dependent on the process states.

Comment: The question is not about how many processes you can create. It is about how many processes can be found at one time in the queue of each state.

Comment: Then the answer is not really much different. The only one that can be specified is the number of processes in either of the running states, which total is going to be the same as the number of cores. The processes in the other states is dependent on virtual memory only.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the only states that might be limited by the number of available cores would be the "Created" state, but that's _only_ if process creation can't be preempted in the kernel, which I would guess is probably not true, and the "Running" states (not including "Ready to run"). All other states are likely capped by the maximum number of processes in the kernel process table, which, as has been mentioned, can vary widely and can be tuned...

Comment: This diagram is very poor and out-of-date.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You say that the number of processes in running state should be equal to the number of cores. What if each of the cores support multiple threads?

Comment: @babon "Virtual cores" are still counted as cores IMO.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, exactly. And hence, the OS may look at 2 physical cores as a total of 4 ("virtual") cores and run 4 processess on these 2 physical cores. So, just to clarify, the number of processes != the number of physical cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that as you say:

For user running, kernel running is the number of cores.

For Ready to run/in memory, Ready to run/Swapped, Asleep in Memory, Sleep/Swapped, Zombie - as many

The answer for preemptive and created is **from 0 to n, where n is limited by process table or virtual memory**.

I think you ask that because you are undecided between 1 processes and more processes. 
So the answer is the same as the For Ready to run/in memory, Ready to run/Swapped, Asleep in Memory, Sleep/Swapped, Zombie.